# How to mark a content as character data with twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I would to know if there is a < ! [CDATA[ like with twig.

For example, I would like the following to be consider like string only :

```
{% block name %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is that possible ?

Thank you

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) twig native tag what you are looking for?

Something like

```
{% verbatim %}
    {% block name %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like,

```
{{ "{% block name%}" }}
{{ "{% endblock %}" }}
```